Firewall to white- or black-list incoming requests
Well over a decade ago, when I was a Windows user, I used a Kaspersky firewall that would pop up when an application wanted was receiving a connection and allow me to allow or deny such connections.
Is there any program for Ubuntu that has similar functionality?
Or anything that has a similar offering. I want to block all network traffic except for selected sites. I have searched but not found a solution that worked for the use case, e.g. Squid and DNSMasq have to be setup with each application.
Ideally it would work on the fly, as mentioned. So I can allow anything that is actually needed.
